# What's the difference between gets and readline?

Tags: ruby

As far as I know, both of them can read from the console.
I know `gets` can read from a file too, but I am interested in console-input. 
Example:

```
a = readline.chomp
puts a
a = gets.chomp
puts a
```

This gives me the same output. So what's the difference for console-input?

Answer (score 5):

From [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-readline) about `Kernel#readline`:

> Equivalent to `Kernel::gets`, except `readline` raises `EOFError` at end of file.

`gets` returns `nil` at end of input.

You can see the difference easily:

```
echo -n "" | ruby -e "gets"        # no error
echo -n "" | ruby -e "readline"    # -e:1:in `readline': end of file reached (EOFError)
```